# ValueError: time data '2020-02-02T10:21:20.000Z' does not match format '%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S.%z

Tags: python

I do have some trouble getting datetime to parse this time data.

`new_data['play_time'] = pd.to_datetime(new_data['play_time'], format = '%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S.%z')`

Error:

```
ValueError: time data '2020-02-02T10:21:20.000Z' does not match format '%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S.%z' (match)
```

Comment: That's because it should have been %Y-%m-%d?

Comment: Do you know what you are writing there? I mean, you are specifing `%d-%m-%Y`, but your input does not match that formular at all... Please read the documentation of [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and ask again... :|

Answer (score 0):

`play_time` is '2020-02-02T10:21:20.000Z' but your format is '%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S.%z'

%Y - 2020
%d - 02
%m - 02
%H - 10
%M - 21
%S - 20
%f - 000

All together, the format of `play_time` is: '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'

These two do not match:
%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S.%z
%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S.%fZ

Python Interpreter:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("2020-02-02T10:21:20.000Z", "%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 2, 10, 21, 20)
```